# Is there a better way of downloading nuget packages required for .NET work for an offline enviroment?

Tags: visual-studio, download, nuget, offline

Currently facing a problem where I have an offline enviroment with Visual Studio on it. Web Application development works fine with my offline Visual Studio installer, absolutely no problems there. But when it comes to MSTest and other things, I seem to be running into issues with missing nuget packages.

As far as I can make out there's no installers that provide these packages (things like Microsoft.VisualStudio etc) and the best way seems to be to let a machine with internet connectivity download the packages during a restore operation and then drag the packages over. But surely this isn't right - Microsoft surely support offline development better than this.

Does anyone have any experience or recommendations with regards to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to create a local nuget package source which stores the related nuget packages. When you use it, you do not need to come to the network to perform the restore operation in the future.

**No matter** how you realize it, you have to connect to the Internet once to download these packages from Internet into your local disk. After that, you do not need to connect to the Internet for your MSTest projects.

Under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Sources**

create a local nuget package source called **Local Cache** and set a value for it.

**In my side**, the value is `C:\Local Caches`

[image]

Please do not forget to click **Update** button.

**Then**, Please enter [nuget.org webiste](https://www.nuget.org/) and download these packages and then copy these nupkg files into the local folder `C:\Local Caches`.

- [Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 16.7.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk/16.7.1)
- [Microsoft.CodeCoverage 16.7.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeCoverage/16.7.1)
- [Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost 16.7.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost/16.7.1)
- [Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel 16.7.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TestPlatform.ObjectModel/16.7.1)
- [NuGet.Frameworks 5.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Frameworks/5.5.0)
- [coverlet.collector 1.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/coverlet.collector/1.3.0)
- [mstest.testadapter 2.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter/2.1.1)
- [mstest.testframework 2.1.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/2.1.1)
- [system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener 4.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener/4.3.0)
- [system.diagnostics.tracesource 4.3.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource/4.3.0)

Copy them into the local path:

[image]

**After that**, you do not need to connect to Internet when you create the MSTest project.

Every time you faced the loss of nuget packages on your offline environment, you should download the related nuget packages into your local nuget source.

This is the only way for the offline environment, and it is not as convenient as the network environment. Compared with network environment, offline needs to be considered more.

============================

**Update 1**

Every nuget package has its own nuget dependencies. And its complexity depends on the author of the package, and we have no right to make any changes to it. If you insist on using an offline environment, then you have to do these. Or you could try this which could be more easier: first, delete all nuget cahes under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`.

**Then**, connect Internet, open VS, create any projects which you want to use, then build them once.

**All** of the required nuget packages will store under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`. The nuget packages which you are used for all project templates are listed under that folder. In this function, you no longer need to manually query their dependencies one by one, and copy all the contents of the `packages` folder to the local `Local Caches` folder at once. This is more convenient.

Comment: Thanks. A local nuget repository is being used, and the suggestion of copying the packages from nuget.org was one I had considered, but when I tried it they all seemed to have their own dependency chains adding up to quite a lot of files, which is why the route of letting an internet connected machine download them sounded easier.

Comment: Yes. As you said, every nuget package has its own nuget dependencies. And its complexity depends on the author of the package, and we have no right to make any changes to it. If you insist on using an offline environment, then you have to do these.  Or you could try this which could be more easier: first, delete all nuget cahes under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`. Then, connect Internet,open VS, create any projects which you want to use, then build them once.

Comment: All of the required nuget packages will store under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`. The nuget packages which you are used for all project templates are listed under that folder.  In this function, you no longer need to manually query their dependencies one by one, and copy all the contents of the `packages` folder to the local `Local Caches` folder at once. This is more convenient.